# How to make DomDocument or SimpleXMLElement actually case sensitive when saving to XML text?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

Everything is about PHP.
I think example will do the best.
I want the node to be `<shippingCost>23</shippingCost>`. But instead, xml outputs me `<shippingcost>23</shippingcost>`. I want to connect to an private external API, which only accepts the first form.

I was trying to use DomDocument and SimpleXMLElement classes in PHP, no of them could output me xml code without case-folding to lowercase. I was searching for some options too in both, but no of them was about lowercasing.

```
$input_xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","utf-8");
        $super_root = addChild($input_xml,$input_xml,'orderExport','');
// ^ this gives me <orderexport></orderexport>
...
function addChild($doc,$node,$marker,$value){
    $temp = $doc->createElement($marker);
    $temp->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($value));
    $node->appendChild($temp);
    return $temp;
}
... 
addChild($input_xml,$shipping_info,'shippingEmail',$mail);
...
$output = $input_xml->saveXml()
```

I expect to get for example

```
<camelCase>123</camelCase>
```

tag, but i get

```
<camelcase>123</camelcase>
```

Comment: You example code outputs camel case (https://3v4l.org/COsFW). Maybe you threat it as HTML somewhere? *btw* `appendChild()` returns the appended node, you can use that to nest/chain the calls.

Comment: You are sure, it was lowercased when i inspected html in chrome, after rightclick and view source code, all the letters were as original. I don't chain nodes in one line, but i wrote it that way so i can append childs to element later

Comment: @yossi Rather than inspecting the output using a web browser, save the output, and inspect it with a text editor. Web browsers are primarily built for dealing with HTML, which doesn't work the same way as XML, so they make lots of assumptions and "clean up" what they're given.